# AWS: When assuming a role in a child account, how can I keep access to permissions in parent account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am setting up a multi-account architecture in AWS. I have my domain hosted in route53 in the root account. When creating infrastructure in the child account with CDK, I need to be able to create route53 records (e.g. root domain is test.com and I want to have dev.test.com controlled by the child account). AWS mentions two ways to do this: one is to delegate the record set. The other is to use cross-account permissions.

I'm trying to use a cross-account role to achieve this. I've created a role in the child account and have permissions to assume that role in the parent account.

When I run `cdk deploy`, all the infrastructure successfully deploys except for the record set because the role apparently doesn't have permission.

Here's what my CDK code looks like:

```
    this.hostedZone = route53.HostedZone.fromHostedZoneAttributes(this, 'test.com hosted zone', {
      hostedZoneId: 'Z2H17K123M6123',
      zoneName: 'test.co'
    });

    new route53.TxtRecord(this, 'TXTRecord', {
      zone: this.hostedZone,
      recordName: '_foo', // If the name ends with a ".", it will be used as-is;
      // if it ends with a "." followed by the zone name, a trailing "." will be added automatically;
      // otherwise, a ".", the zone name, and a trailing "." will be added automatically.
      // Defaults to zone root if not specified.
      values: [
        // Will be quoted for you, and " will be escaped automatically.
        'Bar!',
        'Baz?'
      ],
      ttl: cdk.Duration.minutes(90) // Optional - default is 30 minutes
    });
```

The error I get is:

```
API: route53:GetHostedZone User: arn:aws:sts::123:assumed-role/ROLENAME/123 is not authorized to access this resource
new RecordSet (.../infrastructure/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-route53/lib/record-set.ts:122:23)
```

This is the policy I have for the role (I had it scoped to the hosted zone in the root account originally but then made it *):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "route53:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I give this role (which is assumed from the parent account) access to route53 in the parent account?

The command I use to run cdk deploy is:

`aws-vault exec myorg-prestaging -- npx cdk deploy backend-api`

Where myorg-prestaging is a profile configured as so:

```
[profile myorg]
region=ap-southeast-2
mfa_serial=arn:aws:iam::12332:mfa/jeremy@myorg.co

[profile myorg-prestaging]
region=ap-southeast-2
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::12333:role/GOFARPRESTAGINGROLE
source_profile = myorg
```

Comment: can you post the policy that you assigned to the role that gives the permission to Route53 actions

Comment: Are you able to assume the role . Did you try to assume the role in the console

Comment: Yes I can assume the role in the console and via cdk. I am able to create infrastructure in the child account without any issues.

Comment: Everything works except creating route53 create record set?

Comment: Yup. If I use a hosted zone in the child account, the entire stack is created without problems.

Answer (score 0):

you have to assign the permissions to child role that the parent is assuming.

this is how it works
1. a parent User should have permission to assume a role (IAM policy)
2. the role on the child account should allow the parent account to assume the role (trust policy).
3. the role on the child account should have another policy attached that allows the role to perform actions on resources.

I don't think there is a way for parent to define this permissions.

Comment: I have a policy on the role in the child account that allows all actions on route53 without any restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it working so I delegated the subdomain to the child account (by setting NS records in the root account to the name servers of the child account). This worked perfectly.